# 2/3D Geometry: How to optimally align two lists of points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, matching

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows: Given two lists of equal length containing points, find a mapping that minimizes the sum of distances between pairs. The reason I'm trying to do this is to find the closest points in two polygons for a genetic algorithm I'm building, that would ideally line up two genes based on the output of this computation to maximize the spatial similarity.

Comment: that's a little vague, more info please?

Answer (score 4):

This is known as the [linear assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). The [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is one way to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the name, that helped my search a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I actually asked basically the same question a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550557/need-better-algorithm-for-finding-mapping-between-2-sets-of-points-with-minimum-d). There are a bunch of good links to explanations of possible solutions including simulated annealing.